# Text not coming proper in drop down box in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

[image: Text not coming proper in IE9 combo box]

As shown in attached image I am getting this issue in IE9 combo box.

Issue : **a** is missing from **Honda** in selected option of combo

If we change font family to Arial in place of Verdana everything works fine. Secondly this issue is coming only in IE9  browser. In other IE versions its working properly .
Any solution for this ??